# Adding a textbox to a pgfplot

Tags: pgfplots, nodes, matlab2tikz

From Matlab I have a set of data from which i create a graph. The plot with Latex works perfectly fine. To this plot I am adding a coloured square in the background, which is also working. Here a first problem occur. When the square is plotted, the line connecting the markers disappear, is it some kind of layer problem?

My main question is, how do I put a text box inside (in the middle of) the plot? This box should have a border, and an arrow which points from the box to one of the marker points from the curve. The text will have up to 3 lines and will contain math formulas. My first attempt with `pgfplotsset` shows text, but I don't know how to set the distance and the box border.

My second attempt by using `draw` shows an arrow, but it will disappear when the coloured squared is plotted, and somehow this doesn't allow text with more than one line (`\\` or `\newline` don't work). Maybe it can also be done, that the selected marker will be made bold or highlighted?

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[%
   width=4.521in,
   scale = 0.6,
   height=3.566in,
   at={(0.758in,0.481in)},
   scale only axis,
   separate axis lines,
   every outer x axis line/.append style={black},
   every x tick label/.append style={font=\color{black}},
   xmin=-0.1,
   xmax=1.1,
   xtick={-0.1,  0,  0.1,  0.2,  0.3,  0.4,  0.5,  0.6,  0.7,  0.8,    0.9,  1,  1.1},
   xminorticks=true,
   xlabel={FAR},
   every outer y axis line/.append style={black},
   every y tick label/.append style={font=\color{black}},
   ymin=-0.1,
   ymax=1.2,
   ytick={-0.1,  0,  0.1,  0.2,  0.3,  0.4,  0.5,  0.6,  0.7,  0.8,  0.9,  1,  1.1,  1.2},
   yminorticks=true,
   ylabel={TPR},
   axis background/.style={fill=white},
   ]
   \addplot [color=blue,solid,mark=o,mark options={solid},forget plot]   %only marks
   table[row sep=crcr]{%
   1    1\\
   1    1\\
   1    1\\
   1    1\\
   0.990942028985507    1\\
   0.919466403162056    1\\
   0.750101951188908    1\\
   0.543799799234582    1\\
   0.392296411318151    0.958333333333333\\
   0.29586627140975 0.958333333333333\\
   0.227355072463768    0.916666666666667\\
   0.181159420289855    0.875\\
   0.148962450592885    0.791666666666667\\
   0.106966403162055    0.75\\
   0.0707345191040843   0.75\\
   0.039937417654809    0.708333333333333\\
   0.0271739130434783   0.666666666666667\\
   0.0145750988142293   0.625\\
   0.00543478260869565  0.541666666666667\\
   0.00181159420289855  0.5\\
   0    0.375\\
   0    0.333333333333333\\
   0    0.291666666666667\\
   0    0.25\\
   0    0.25\\
   0    0.25\\
   0    0.25\\
   0    0.166666666666667\\
   0    0.166666666666667\\
   0    0.125\\
   0    0.125\\
   0    0.125\\
   0    0.125\\
   0    0.125\\
   0    0.125\\
   0    0.125\\
   0    0.125\\
   0    0.125\\
   0    0.0833333333333333\\
   0    0.0416666666666667\\
   0    0.0416666666666667\\
   0    0.0416666666666667\\
   0    0.0416666666666667\\
   0    0.0416666666666667\\
   0    0\\
   0    0\\
   0    0\\
   0    0\\
   0    0\\
   0    0\\
   0    0\\
   0    0\\
   0    0\\
   0    0\\
   0    0\\
   0    0\\
   0    0\\
   0    0\\
   0    0\\
   0    0\\
   0    0\\
   0    0\\
   0    0\\
   0    0\\
   0    0\\
   0    0\\
   0    0\\
   0    0\\
   0    0\\
   0    0\\
   0    0\\
   0    0\\
   0    0\\
   0    0\\
   0    0\\
   0    0\\
   0    0\\
   0    0\\
   0    0\\
   0    0\\
   0    0\\
   0    0\\
   0    0\\
   0    0\\
   0    0\\
   0    0\\
   0    0\\
   0    0\\
   0    0\\
   0    0\\
   0    0\\
   0    0\\
   0    0\\
   0    0\\
   0    0\\
   0    0\\
   0    0\\
   0    0\\
   0    0\\
   0    0\\
   0    0\\
   };
   %first attempt:
   %\pgfplotsset{
   %    after end axis/.code={      
   %        \node[pin={[text width=3cm,pin edge={black}]-45:       {\tiny{sample: text text\\ more text text\\$math equation: \phi$}}}] at      (axis cs:0.181, 0.875) { };  
   %    }
   %}

   % Second attemp:
   %\draw[<-](axis cs:0.181,    0.875)-- +(10pt,10pt) node[right] {here\\ test};

   \fill [blue!10!white,rounded corners] (axis cs:0,0) rectangle (axis cs:1,1);

   \end{axis}
   \end{tikzpicture}%
   \end{document}
```

This image using `pgfplotsset`:

[image: Image using pgfplotsset]

Here i used `\draw`:

[image: Image using \draw]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To draw the coloured square behind the plot, simply place the `\fill` before the `\addplot`. Usually stuff is drawn in the order they're added to the code, so by adding the `\fill` first it ends up on the bottom.

To add the box with the text you can use something like this:

```
\draw[->,shorten >=1mm,shorten <=1mm] (rel axis cs:0.5,0.5) node[right,draw,align=left] {here\\ test}  -- (axis cs:0.181, 0.875);
```

`rel axis cs` is a coordinate system where (0,0) is the lower left corner of the axis, and (1,1) the upper right, so (0.5,0.5) is the middle. To allow for line breaks in a node you have to add either a specific alignment of the text (here `align=left`) or set the width of the text area in the node (e.g. `text width=2cm`). `shorten <` and `shorten >` shortens respectively the beginning and end of the line by the specified length.

To draw the border of a `node`, simply add `draw` to its options, as seen above. If you want to draw it with a specific colour, say blue, then write `draw=blue`. (Similarly you add filling of the background, with `fill=<colorname>`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[%
   width=4.521in,
   scale = 0.6,
   height=3.566in,
   at={(0.758in,0.481in)},
   scale only axis,
   separate axis lines,
   every outer x axis line/.append style={black},
   every x tick label/.append style={font=\color{black}},
   xmin=-0.1,
   xmax=1.1,
   xtick={-0.1,  0,  0.1,  0.2,  0.3,  0.4,  0.5,  0.6,  0.7,  0.8,    0.9,  1,  1.1},
   xminorticks=true,
   xlabel={FAR},
   every outer y axis line/.append style={black},
   every y tick label/.append style={font=\color{black}},
   ymin=-0.1,
   ymax=1.2,
   ytick={-0.1,  0,  0.1,  0.2,  0.3,  0.4,  0.5,  0.6,  0.7,  0.8,  0.9,  1,  1.1,  1.2},
   yminorticks=true,
   ylabel={TPR},
   axis background/.style={fill=white},
   ]

   \fill [blue!10!white,rounded corners] (axis cs:0,0) rectangle (axis cs:1,1);

   \addplot [color=blue,solid,mark=o,mark options={solid},forget plot]   %only marks
   table[row sep=crcr]{%
   1    1\\
   1    1\\
   1    1\\
   1    1\\
   0.990942028985507    1\\
   0.919466403162056    1\\
   0.750101951188908    1\\
   0.543799799234582    1\\
   0.392296411318151    0.958333333333333\\
   0.29586627140975 0.958333333333333\\
   0.227355072463768    0.916666666666667\\
   0.181159420289855    0.875\\
   0.148962450592885    0.791666666666667\\
   0.106966403162055    0.75\\
   0.0707345191040843   0.75\\
   0.039937417654809    0.708333333333333\\
   0.0271739130434783   0.666666666666667\\
   0.0145750988142293   0.625\\
   0.00543478260869565  0.541666666666667\\
   0.00181159420289855  0.5\\
   0    0.375\\
   0    0.333333333333333\\
   0    0.291666666666667\\
   0    0.25\\
   0    0.25\\
   0    0.25\\
   0    0.25\\
   0    0.166666666666667\\
   0    0.166666666666667\\
   0    0.125\\
   0    0.125\\
   0    0.125\\
   0    0.125\\
   0    0.125\\
   0    0.125\\
   0    0.125\\
   0    0.125\\
   0    0.125\\
   0    0.0833333333333333\\
   0    0.0416666666666667\\
   0    0.0416666666666667\\
   0    0.0416666666666667\\
   0    0.0416666666666667\\
   0    0.0416666666666667\\
   0    0\\
   0    0\\
   0    0\\
   0    0\\
   0    0\\
   0    0\\
   0    0\\
   0    0\\
   0    0\\
   0    0\\
   0    0\\
   0    0\\
   0    0\\
   0    0\\
   0    0\\
   0    0\\
   0    0\\
   0    0\\
   0    0\\
   0    0\\
   0    0\\
   0    0\\
   0    0\\
   0    0\\
   0    0\\
   0    0\\
   0    0\\
   0    0\\
   0    0\\
   0    0\\
   0    0\\
   0    0\\
   0    0\\
   0    0\\
   0    0\\
   0    0\\
   0    0\\
   0    0\\
   0    0\\
   0    0\\
   0    0\\
   0    0\\
   0    0\\
   0    0\\
   0    0\\
   0    0\\
   0    0\\
   0    0\\
   0    0\\
   0    0\\
   0    0\\
   0    0\\
   0    0\\
   0    0\\
   0    0\\
   0    0\\
   0    0\\
   };


   \draw[->,shorten >=1mm,shorten <=1mm] (rel axis cs:0.5,0.5) node[right,draw,align=left] {here\\ test}  -- (axis cs:0.181,    0.875);


\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}
```

## Second version

Here the data is saved to a table first. Values from a specific row in the table is read and saved to macros `\myX` and `\myY` using

```
\pgfplotstablegetelem{10}{[index]0}\of{\mydata}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\myX}{\pgfplotsretval}
\pgfplotstablegetelem{10}{[index]1}\of{\mydata}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\myY}{\pgfplotsretval}
```

The `\pgfplotstablegetelem{<row no>}{<column>}` macro retrieves the specified value from the table and saves it to `\pgfplotsretval`. `\pgfmathsetmacro` is used to define `\myX` and `\myY`, which in turn are used to draw a red circle, and place the arrow.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotstableread[row sep=crcr]{%
   1    1\\
   1    1\\
   1    1\\
   1    1\\
   0.990942028985507    1\\
   0.919466403162056    1\\
   0.750101951188908    1\\
   0.543799799234582    1\\
   0.392296411318151    0.958333333333333\\
   0.29586627140975 0.958333333333333\\
   0.227355072463768    0.916666666666667\\
   0.181159420289855    0.875\\
   0.148962450592885    0.791666666666667\\
   0.106966403162055    0.75\\
   0.0707345191040843   0.75\\
   0.039937417654809    0.708333333333333\\
   0.0271739130434783   0.666666666666667\\
   0.0145750988142293   0.625\\
   0.00543478260869565  0.541666666666667\\
   0.00181159420289855  0.5\\
   0    0.375\\
   0    0.333333333333333\\
   0    0.291666666666667\\
   0    0.25\\
   0    0.25\\
   0    0.25\\
   0    0.25\\
   0    0.166666666666667\\
   0    0.166666666666667\\
   0    0.125\\
   0    0.125\\
   0    0.125\\
   0    0.125\\
   0    0.125\\
   0    0.125\\
   0    0.125\\
   0    0.125\\
   0    0.125\\
   0    0.0833333333333333\\
   0    0.0416666666666667\\
   0    0.0416666666666667\\
   0    0.0416666666666667\\
   0    0.0416666666666667\\
   0    0.0416666666666667\\
   0    0\\
   0    0\\
   0    0\\
   0    0\\
   0    0\\
   0    0\\
   0    0\\
   0    0\\
   0    0\\
   0    0\\
   0    0\\
   0    0\\
   0    0\\
   0    0\\
   0    0\\
   0    0\\
   0    0\\
   0    0\\
   0    0\\
   0    0\\
   0    0\\
   0    0\\
   0    0\\
   0    0\\
   0    0\\
   0    0\\
   0    0\\
   0    0\\
   0    0\\
   0    0\\
   0    0\\
   0    0\\
   0    0\\
   0    0\\
   0    0\\
   0    0\\
   0    0\\
   0    0\\
   0    0\\
   0    0\\
   0    0\\
   0    0\\
   0    0\\
   0    0\\
   0    0\\
   0    0\\
   0    0\\
   0    0\\
   0    0\\
   0    0\\
   0    0\\
   0    0\\
   0    0\\
   0    0\\
   0    0\\
   0    0\\
   0    0\\
}\mydata
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[%
   width=4.521in,
   scale = 0.6,
   height=3.566in,
   at={(0.758in,0.481in)},
   scale only axis,
   separate axis lines,
   every outer x axis line/.append style={black},
   every x tick label/.append style={font=\color{black}},
   xmin=-0.1,
   xmax=1.1,
   xtick={-0.1,  0,  0.1,  0.2,  0.3,  0.4,  0.5,  0.6,  0.7,  0.8,    0.9,  1,  1.1},
   xminorticks=true,
   xlabel={FAR},
   every outer y axis line/.append style={black},
   every y tick label/.append style={font=\color{black}},
   ymin=-0.1,
   ymax=1.2,
   ytick={-0.1,  0,  0.1,  0.2,  0.3,  0.4,  0.5,  0.6,  0.7,  0.8,  0.9,  1,  1.1,  1.2},
   yminorticks=true,
   ylabel={TPR},
   axis background/.style={fill=white},
   ]

   \fill [blue!10!white,rounded corners] (axis cs:0,0) rectangle (axis cs:1,1);

   \addplot [color=blue,solid,mark=o,mark options={solid},forget plot]   %only marks
   table {\mydata};


   % change the number 10 (row number in table) to select a different marker
   \pgfplotstablegetelem{10}{[index]0}\of{\mydata}
   \pgfmathsetmacro{\myX}{\pgfplotsretval}
   \pgfplotstablegetelem{10}{[index]1}\of{\mydata}
   \pgfmathsetmacro{\myY}{\pgfplotsretval}

   \node[draw,align=left] (textbox) at (rel axis cs:0.5,0.5)  {here\\ test \\ $f(x)=\int\sin x\,\mathrm{d}x$};
   \draw[->,shorten >=2mm] (textbox) -- (axis cs:\myX,\myY) node[draw,circle,red,inner sep=0pt,minimum size=7pt,very thick]{};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}
```

Comment: Perfect! This is helpful and what i was looking for. Very well described. Thank you

Comment: Hi @TorbjørnT . I write here because I need just one advice regarding your "first-version" solution. If I would like to draw a circle instead of ">" at the end of the arrow, what symbol or command should I replace  in the line  `\draw[->,shorten >=1mm,shorten <=1mm]` ? In this way I could point out a specific point on my plot in a similar way you have done in your second-version solution.

Comment: @Catarella If you add `\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}` to the preamble, you can use e.g. `\draw[-{Circle[open, width=6pt, length=6pt]},shorten >=-3pt,shorten <=1mm] (rel axis cs:0.5,0.5) node[right,draw,align=left] {here\\ test}  -- (axis cs:0.181,    0.875);`. It's not entirely clear to me what you wanted though. Note here I set the `shorten >` length to half the circle radius, which means the circle is centered on the end coordinate of the path.

Comment: Thank you @TorbjørnT. that's exactly what I needed. You nailed it!